# Android Studio Get request java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://10.0.2.2

Tags: android, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, android-studio, android-emulator

I am working on android app that should send GCS registration token to .NET MVC service that is running on localhost. I am using android Emulator with API 23 version. I have eliminated nearly everything that can be wrong, URL and parameters I send at the moment are hardcoded and If I copy paste url into browser (and replace 10.0.2.2 with localhost obviously) everything works. I am using fiddler but request that is supposed to originate from android does not get registered.

What I am getting instead is IO exception on `InputStream inputStream = connection.getInputStream();` line

> 1-18 18:26:28.305 3488-3524/gcm.play.android.samples.com.gcmquickstart
>   W/System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException:
>   http://10.0.2.2:61594/api/Account/RegisterDevice?token=2342342&coordinates=12.012;13.1515
>   01-18 18:26:28.305
>   3488-3524/gcm.play.android.samples.com.gcmquickstart W/System.err:
>   at
>   com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:238)
>   01-18 18:26:28.305
>   3488-3524/gcm.play.android.samples.com.gcmquickstart W/System.err:
>   at
>   gcm.play.android.samples.com.gcmquickstart.RegistrationIntentService.sendRegistrationToServer(RegistrationIntentService.java:108)
>   01-18 18:26:28.305
>   3488-3524/gcm.play.android.samples.com.gcmquickstart W/System.err:
>   at
>   gcm.play.android.samples.com.gcmquickstart.RegistrationIntentService.onHandleIntent(RegistrationIntentService.java:69)
>   01-18 18:26:28.305
>   3488-3524/gcm.play.android.samples.com.gcmquickstart W/System.err:
>   at
>   android.app.IntentService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(IntentService.java:66)
>   01-18 18:26:28.306
>   3488-3524/gcm.play.android.samples.com.gcmquickstart W/System.err:
>   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 01-18
>   18:26:28.306 3488-3524/gcm.play.android.samples.com.gcmquickstart
>   W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 01-18
>   18:26:28.306 3488-3524/gcm.play.android.samples.com.gcmquickstart
>   W/System.err:     at
>   android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)

In watch `connection.getResponseCode()` status code is 400 (bad request) - but again server isn't even being hit.

I have configured following permissions in manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Code that makes request:

```
StringBuffer chaine = new StringBuffer("");
    try{
        URL url = new URL("http://10.0.2.2:61594/api/Account/RegisterDevice?token=2342342&coordinates=12.012;13.1515");
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
        connection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "");
        connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.connect();

        InputStream inputStream = connection.getInputStream();

        BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
        String line = "";
        while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
            chaine.append(line);
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        // writing exception to log
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Code from .NET Server

```
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [System.Web.Http.AcceptVerbs("GET", "POST")]
    [System.Web.Http.HttpGet]
    public void RegisterDevice(string token, string coordinates)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(token))
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("Token is empty");
        }

        var data = new Data.EmergencyService();
        if (data.AddUser(token, coordinates))
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Response.StatusCode = 200;
        }
    }
```

After I couldn't get fiddler to register request it made me to be completely lost.

**Why can't I make request GET request from Andriod Studio which perfectly works in browser?**

Comment: Is you android device connected to the same network(i.e: wiffi) than the server?...Another doubt, if you connect from another pc on your network, and in a browser you enter http://10.0.2.2:61594/api/Account/RegisterDevice?token=2342342&coordinates=12.012;13.1515  works or don't?

Comment: @Hackerman I am using android emulator, don't have other devices that could be used to test, but I am sure it wouldn't work, since 10.0.2.2 is localhost from emulator.

Comment: You didn't answer the question xD...on you emulator, do you have internet access?...it seems a network issue to me

Comment: @Hackerman yes emulator does have internet access, works fine, rechecked just in case.

Comment: If you add this line: `int code = connection.getResponseCode();`, what is the actual value of the code var?

Comment: @Hackerman  it is 400

Comment: 400 is Bad Request....if you change your url value to `http://www.google.com` it works fine, right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101007/discussion-between-matas-vaitkevicius-and-hackerman).

Comment: @Hackerman In case you were wondering, I have found reason it was failing. :) Thanks, for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok for those who are wondering the reason for Android not being able to access PC localhost on `http://10.0.2.2` was me running MVC service from Visual Studio in debug mode.

Once I have configured local IIS server and published website ( to local file system), Android was able to access it on `http://10.0.2.2`.

Hope this saves you some time.